# How are the Convolution kernels learned?

Tags: deep-learning, keras, tensorflow, cnn, convolution

As I went through the basics of machine learning, I failed to understand how do the Convolutional layers in a CNN **learn** the convolution kernels. After looking at first few tutorials, I thought the kernels were fixed: for example, there was a 2D kernel which extracts vertical lines, another one extracted horizontal lines etc. Later on I realized that kernels are learned by the network and not fixed.

Is there a good explanation on how the learning goes, how does the backpropagation work (compared to fully connected layers), what is the optimization function, etc.?

p.s.
Let this be an example function to explain: https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/.

Comment: This helps: http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the kernel function is very difficult to choose in a fixed form even if once found it would be easier. It can be learned to map the data in a features space (Hilbert space) through an Convex Optimisation method such as Semidefinite programming, using Hyperkernels, etc.

Some very usefull papers for your question can be found here:

[Learning the Kernel via Convex Optimisation](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/pdf/kernel_learning_icassp08.pdf)

[Learning the Kernel Matrix with Semidefinite Programming](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1709.06557.pdf)

[Learning the Kernel with Hyperkernels](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume6/ong05a/ong05a.pdf)

[Learning the Kernel Function via Regularization](http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/volume6/micchelli05a/micchelli05a.pdf)

I hope that answers your question

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly, convolutional kernels are learned through plain **backpropagation**. The model propagates the error to kernel parameters just as it does with more canonical dense parameters, and trains them accordingly.

The kernels are not fixed, it is known that learned filters are much more powerful than fixed *a priori* ones.

This is one of the cases in which the visualization of it is actually more complex than the math behind (IMHO).

If you are looking for detailed explanations, [this article](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/an-intuitive-guide-to-convolutional-neural-networks-260c2de0a050/) is a very good explanation of all the details of convolution, then I found [this one](https://becominghuman.ai/back-propagation-in-convolutional-neural-networks-intuition-and-code-714ef1c38199) and [this one](https://www.jefkine.com/general/2016/09/05/backpropagation-in-convolutional-neural-networks/) that how backprop works more specifically. They are a bit more technical though.